# unable to display json data on ejs template

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, ejs

I am trying to showing json data in ejs template but i am failed. my json data format is-

```
{ faq:
   [ { name: 'How do I get desktop admin privilege?',
       ans: 'Please login to http://google.com',
       link: 'http://google.com' },
     { name: 'How do I get laptop admin privilege?',
       ans: 'Please login to http://google.com',
       link: 'http://google.com' } 
   ] 
}
```

i sent this data by context data.

now i want to print all name on template.
approch which i am follwing-
result is context variable name

```
    <% if(result.length>0){ %>
        <% for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++) { %>

         <a class="accordion-toggle"  href="#collapseOne">
           <h4 class="question"><%= result.faq[0][i].name %></h4>

          </a>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your `i` index is not set right - I think it should be `result.faq[i].name` and the `for` loop should be till `result.faq.length` - for full answer please share your `result` object

Comment: @DavidWinder is correct, as is goarun112's answer below, but just to expand on what's happening in your code: If `result` is an object and not an array, as seems to be the case, `result.length` will be `undefined`. `i < undefined` will always return `false`, so your `for` loop will never be entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ForEach try this code

```
<% result.faq.forEach( function (element) { %> 
                 <%= element.name %>  
                 <%= element.ans %>  
                 <%= element.link %>  
  <% }); %>
```